# How to calculate sum previous sum in Python django

Tags: python, django, sum

I have table project, project has sub project and subproject has developers. Another table sprint, work distribute in sprint 1 2 ..n so on, Each sprint has different developers data. Now How can i calculate sum, current sprint value and percentage complete Using Django Orm.

Project has sub project foreign key

```
 class project(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        project = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name="subproject", blank=True, null=True)

  Developers table

  class Developers(models.Model):
        quantity = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
        charge_rate = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
        project = models.ForeignKey("Project", on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                 related_name="developers",  null=True)

Table Sprint

class Sprint(models.Model):
    sprint_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    percentage = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

sprint data

class SprintsData(models.Model):
    sprint = models.ForeignKey(
        "project", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="d",
        blank=True)
    percentage = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

This is sample data

project

```
id name         project
1  development  null
```

Sub project

```
id   name       project
 1  Homepage     1
 2  header       1
 3  footer       1
```

Developers

```
id   name        quantity rate  project (sub project foreign key)
1    developers   5       200    1
2    designer      5       150    2
```

Sprint

```
id     name    start_date end_date
1     sprint1    -           -
```

SprintsData

```
id    sprint  project(subproject foreign key)  percentage
 1      1          1                               5
 2      1          2                               80
```

Output looks like

```
sprint    project      sub_project   total_sum             percentage_complete current_sprint_amount
sprint1  development     Homepage   (quantity*charge_rate)         5              (total_sum)5% 
sprint1  development     Header        5*150                       80             (5*150)*80%
```

Comment: the models does not correspond with your sample data. I believe your sample data is the correct one, right?

Comment: Suggest some solution

Comment: can you fix your question first plz? your models does not contain same rows as your sample data. for example, class Sprint has 'sprint_name' and 'percentage' fields, but your Sprint sample data contains only 'name', 'start-date' and 'end-date'. Which one is true?

Comment: Sprint data also has more filed SprintsData table contains sprint foreign key

Comment: so should i guess and answer?

Comment: you are asking for a straight answer, not a suggestion; but you dont give consistent data.

Comment: Ok sugges answer. Can i change  table structure?

Comment: Please prefer this link i get awesome answer from awesome person https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59521332/how-to-calculate-sum-and-also-cumulative-sum-in-django-orm