# How to calculate sum and also cumulative sum in django orm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have table project, project has sub project and subproject has developers. Another table sprint, work distribute in sprint 1 2 ..n so on, Each sprint has different developers data. Now How can i calculate sum, current sprint value and percentage complete Using Django Orm.

Project has sub project foreign key

```
 class project(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        project = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name="subproject", blank=True, null=True)

  Developers table

  class Developers(models.Model):
        quantity = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
        charge_rate = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
        project = models.ForeignKey("Project", on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                 related_name="developers",  null=True)

Table Sprint

class Sprint(models.Model):
    sprint_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    percentage = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

sprint data

class SprintsData(models.Model):
    sprint = models.ForeignKey(
        "project", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="d",
        blank=True)
    percentage = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

This is sample data

project

```
id name         project
1  development  null
```

Sub project

```
id   name       project
 1  Homepage     1
 2  header       1
 3  footer       1
```

Developers

```
id   name        quantity rate  project (sub project foreign key)
1    developers   5       200    1
2    designer      5       150    2
```

Sprint

```
id     name    start_date end_date
1     sprint1    -           -
```

SprintsData

```
id    sprint  project(subproject foreign key)  percentage
 1      1          1                               5
 2      1          2                               80
```

Output looks like

```
sprint    project      sub_project   total_sum             percentage_complete current_sprint_amount
sprint1  development     Homepage   (quantity*charge_rate)         5              (total_sum)5% 
sprint1  development     Header        5*150                       80             (5*150)*80%
```

Comment: Sum of what for which model?

Comment: Sum from Developers tables please help . I need to display output like above can i change tables foreign key ?

Comment: Sum of quantity*charge_rate for Developers?

Comment: Yes exactly  i need to show each sprint value in sum

Comment: The table you have in the question is grouped by "sub_project" is that what you want?

Comment: I need to show sprint value in sum project divided into sprint and i need to show let see i have sprint1 running then in this sprint our target to do homepage and header which is task of development or main project . If you need sample data then i will edit question

Comment: Okay I think I get it now. You want the sums per SprintsData?

Comment: Yes with remaining sum depend upon total value of Homepage and head also thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the `Sprint` model related to anything? `SprintsData.sprint` is a foreign key to the `project` model

Comment: Project has self field which is sub_project w can just join with project__project i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will return all `SprintsData` objects annotated with `total_sum` and `current_sprint_amount`. From this you should be able to generate your table

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F
SprintsData.objects.annotate(
    total_sum=Sum(F('sprint__developers__quantity') * F('sprint__developers__charge_rate'), output_field=models.FloatField())
).annotate(
    current_sprint_amount=F('total_sum') * F('percentage')
)
```

`SprintsData.sprint` is actually a foreign key to the `project` model which is a little confusing

The `Sprint` model has no relationships to any other model so I'm not sure how you would get the sprint name

Comment: Thanks you very much i will calculate cumulative sum but i got answer !!